# Link list in C and java

Tags: java, c, linked-list

1) Can I create a link list in C with out using pointers (and without using structure) ?

2) Java doesn't use pointers then how linked list are implemented in Java ?

Comment: Did you check the source of `java.util.LinkedList`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. I don't see how it would be possible.
2. Java does have pointers. They're just called references in Java, but they're basically the same thing. Every variable pointing to an object is a reference, or pointer, to the object. If the variable is null, and you try to dereference it, you get a NullPointerException.

Comment: Just don't forget that using pointers is just one possible implementation for references in Java. I don't think most people would call `CompressedOops` in Hotspot a pointer. `NullPointerException` was an unlucky naming choice and Bloch (I think) has said he should've called it `NullReferenceException`.. one thing C# fixed there ;)

Comment: "I don't think most people would call CompressedOops in Hotspot a pointer" - it's a fairly direct representation of an address, though, I don't think it's a stretch to say that implementation is still "basically the same thing" as a pointer. The question was "Java doesn't use pointers then how...". To be strictly accurate one could say, "Java uses a different form of indirection, called references". Theoretically a Java implementation could use some bits in a reference to encode type and/or value, in which case the implementation is less like a pointer. I don't know whether any do.

Comment: @Steve I agree it's not black & white there, I'd describe CompressedOops more as an index into the heap, but it still does map to the address of the object rather simple. About your last point: I *think* I remember that Azul's VM does something quite similar to that actually - their target customers don't care about 32gb heaps so they can use the lower bits for something more useful for them.

Comment: @Voo: I mentioned it because I once spent a week debugging a big integer library implementation (in assembler, not Java), that stored "small" values (up to about 2^30) directly in the handle, with a flag set. For "big" values, the handle contained the pointer. In the case of Java the same trick would let you do autoboxing without allocation, assuming you could figure out how to use a monitor with such an "object".

Answer (score 6):

If you can live with some silly limitations, such as having a fixed maximum length for the list and allocating all of the potential elements up front, you can use indexes to replace pointers.

This can make the elements themselves smaller, since if you know a good boundary on the number of elements (which you have to, for the pre-allocation to work) you can adjust the size of the index, but you can't do that with pointers. For a list with at most 1,000 elements, you might get away with a `uint16_t` index, which is 1/4 the size of a pointer on a 64-bit architecture.

On the other hand, indexing involves address calculations which are not needed when just following direct pointers, so there might be a performance cost.

Comment: "some silly limitations" - silly in precisely the same way that a pool allocator is silly ;-)

Comment: I don't see why it'd be impossible to grow the array later on? (or do we count references as pointers here?) Seems easy enough to me. Actually I'm pretty sure the concurrent hashmap in Java does something along these lines.

Comment: "there might be a performance cost" - depending on the addressing modes offered by the target achitecture, blah blah.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I said *might*! :)

Answer (score 4):

As for 1, I don't think that's possible.

For 2, you should check out this excellent resource http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/

Comment: It is possible.  Use an array, and use pointers instead of indices.  What's not possible is a linked list capable of growing indefinitely.

Comment: @k4rtik: Oli wrote that backwards, he meant indices instead of pointers. Please see unwind's answer (and my answer as well).

Comment: @k4rtik, cha0site: Yes, I wrote that backwards!

Answer (score 3):

for java - it's  references which are being used by LinkedList
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Answer (score 3):

1 - No. The point of a linked list is that it is dynamic data structure. This means that you can change its size at run time (vs having to know what size it is when you compile the program). This can only be done with pointers, because when you allocate some new memory you need to know how to find it.

And you could do it without structs, but they are the most suitable structure.

2 - Java has references to objects. They are basically the same as pointers, except you can't do arithmetic with them, and they are type safe.

Answer (score 2):

1 - Absolutely.  Use a set of parallel arrays (one for each attribute) and use the array indices as your pointers.  Generations of FORTRAN programmers (and college students like myself who learned from those FORTRAN programmers) used this approach for all sorts of data structures - lists, trees, stacks, queues, etc.  It's ugly, it's a huge pain in the ass, it has some real limitations, but it's certainly possible.  Pointer types and aggregate types make implementation of data structures *easier*, but they're hardly required.

2 - Java uses pointers all over the place; it just doesn't expose operations on pointer types to the programmer.  Any time you use a reference type (basically, anything that requires you to use `new` to create an instance) you're working with a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

1) Since all memory allocation somehow involves pointers, and you need to allocate additional memory for new entries in the list, a traditional linked list that grows and shrinks with the number of elements is not possible.

2) Java has *references*, which are the same as pointers, you just can't do pointer arithmetic    (like `int* p = q + 1;`) on them.

Answer (score 0):

1. A linked list in C without pointers or `struct`s? Well... Maybe. You can have a set of arrays, one would contain the data, the other would contain the index of the next node. Of course, arrays use pointers.
2. Java uses reference which are almost, but not quite, pointers.

Answer (score 0):

1) The answer that suggests "silly limitations" is probably your best bet if you absolutely have to, although some of thos limitations compelete defeat the point of using a linked list.  For instance easily resizable goes to impossible to resize.  Why would you want to not use pointers?

2) Just because you don't see them doesn't mean they arent there.  A more accurate statement would be "I don't have to deal with the pointers or their arithmatic in Java."  If you need to prove to yourself that pointers are under the covers do the folowing process with both int and  Integer

0) (we're good code heads)declare and initialize variable to 3
 1) print it
 2) pass it to another function
 3) increment it in that function
 4) print it again
 5) return
 6) print from calling function.

With an int type you will print 3 4 3, with an Integer you will print 3, 4, 4.  This is because objects are passed by reference meaning you are still dealing with pointers under the hood.  References are different because (for the most part) you don't have to deal with them.